# How do i prevent my image link to be the width of the entire page?

Tags: html, css

This here is my html source code:

```
<a href="#section-1">
    <img src="/images/site-images/scrolldown2.png" style="display: block; margin:auto;">
</a>
```

When i try to use it this way to make my image with a width of 196px link to somewhere, the link spans the entire page width. 
**I only want the link to be available when hovering over the image.**

*EDIT: The image needs to stay centered horizontally.*

Comment: Remove the `display:block` from the image style.

Comment: use text-align:center in <a>, remove display block from <img>, add display block in <a> and may be float to anchor

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to see what's going on. Any answers are pure speculation, since so much depends on the parent and sibling elements.  Can you post a link to your page or to a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To align the image, and get what you requested:

Place a class (so that you can style it), remove the inline styles of the image, and specify the width of the `a` and by using the auto left and right margins (and because we specified a width) it will align it to the centre.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#section-1" class="link">
    <img src="/images/site-images/scrolldown2.png">
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.link {
    display: block;
    width: 196px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a href="#section-1" style="margin: 0px auto; display: block; width: 196px">
    <img src="/images/site-images/scrolldown2.png" style="display: block;">
</a>
```

or absolute position:

```
<a href="#section-1" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -98px; display: block; width: 196px">
    <img src="/images/site-images/scrolldown2.png" style="display: block;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your code

```
<a class="my_link" href="#section-1">
    <img src="/images/site-images/scrolldown2.png" style="display: block; margin:auto;">
</a>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/hMR9a/1/

This makes the image not clickable

```
    .my_link{
pointer-events: none;
}
```

This makes the image clickable

```
    .my_link:link{
cursor:pointer !important;
pointer-events: auto;
}
```